# Kusto: Self join table and get values from different rows

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, summarize, kusto-explorer

Working with a similar dataset as below, I am able to get the desired output by using scan operator, to fill forward strings/bools in test dataset, however it's timing out for larger datasets, as every property has many events and there are millions of property. Looking for an better/faster approach.

```
let T = datatable(PropertyId:int, Tenant:string, Owner:string, NoisyNeighbour:bool , PropertyTitle:string, EventDate:datetime )
[
   1, "", "", bool(0),"",datetime(2022-08-01 00:00),
   1, "", "abc", bool(null),"",datetime(2022-08-01 01:00),
   1, "X","", bool(null),"Title updated",datetime(2022-08-02 00:00),
   1, "X", "cde",bool(null),"",datetime(2022-08-03 00:00),
   1, "A1", "",bool(null),"",datetime(2022-08-03 00:00),
   1, "A2", "",bool(null),"",datetime(2022-08-03 02:00),
   1, "A2", "def",bool(null),"",datetime(2022-08-03 03:00),
   1, "B", "", bool(null),"",datetime(2022-08-04 00:00),
   1, "C","", bool(1),"",datetime(2022-08-05 00:00),
   1, "D", "xyz",bool(null),"",datetime(2022-08-06 00:00),
]; T
```

Expected result : Tenant who marked the property with NoisyNeighbor, Date when it was marked noisy, Current owner of the property, property title

Comment: Lacks details. Can a property be marked with NN more than once? Can it be marked and then un-marked? What would be the expected result then? How many properties are? How did you use the scan operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [arg_max()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction)

- For each property find the last time it was marked with NN
- For each property take only the events that preceded the NN event (including itself).
- For each property take the `Tenant` & `NoisyNeighbour` of the last event (the one that was marked with NN) and the last `Owner` & `PropertyTitle` that are not null

---

```
let T = datatable(PropertyId:int, Tenant:string, Owner:string, NoisyNeighbour:bool , PropertyTitle:string, EventDate:datetime )
[
    1 ,""   ,""    ,false      ,""              ,datetime(2022-08-01 00:00)
   ,1 ,""   ,"abc" ,bool(null) ,""              ,datetime(2022-08-01 01:00)
   ,1 ,"X"  ,""    ,bool(null) ,"Title updated" ,datetime(2022-08-02 00:00)
   ,1 ,"X"  ,"cde" ,bool(null) ,""              ,datetime(2022-08-03 00:00)
   ,1 ,"A1" ,""    ,bool(null) ,""              ,datetime(2022-08-03 00:00)
   ,1 ,"A2" ,""    ,bool(null) ,""              ,datetime(2022-08-03 02:00)
   ,1 ,"A2" ,"def" ,bool(null) ,""              ,datetime(2022-08-03 03:00)
   ,1 ,"B"  ,""    ,bool(null) ,""              ,datetime(2022-08-04 00:00)
   ,1 ,"C"  ,""    ,true       ,""              ,datetime(2022-08-05 00:00)
   ,1 ,"D"  ,"xyz" ,bool(null) ,""              ,datetime(2022-08-06 00:00)
];
T
| where         NoisyNeighbour
| summarize     max(EventDate) by PropertyId
| join          kind=inner T on PropertyId
| where         EventDate <= max_EventDate
| summarize     arg_max(EventDate, Tenant, NoisyNeighbour)
               ,arg_max(iff(isnotempty(Owner)         ,EventDate ,datetime(null)) ,Owner) 
               ,arg_max(iff(isnotempty(PropertyTitle) ,EventDate ,datetime(null)) ,PropertyTitle) 
                by PropertyId
| project-away  max*
```

| PropertyId | EventDate | Tenant | NoisyNeighbour | Owner | PropertyTitle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-08-05T00:00:00Z | C | true | def | Title updated |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=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)

Comment: Thanks David, Scan operator times out on larger dataset, however arg_max works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

The [partition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/partitionoperator) operator is used for parallelizing the [scan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scan-operator) operator work.

```
let T = datatable(PropertyId:int, Tenant:string, Owner:string, NoisyNeighbour:bool , PropertyTitle:string, EventDate:datetime )
[
    1 ,""   ,""    ,false      ,""              ,datetime(2022-08-01 00:00)
   ,1 ,""   ,"abc" ,bool(null) ,""              ,datetime(2022-08-01 01:00)
   ,1 ,"X"  ,""    ,bool(null) ,"Title updated" ,datetime(2022-08-02 00:00)
   ,1 ,"X"  ,"cde" ,bool(null) ,""              ,datetime(2022-08-03 00:00)
   ,1 ,"A1" ,""    ,bool(null) ,""              ,datetime(2022-08-03 00:00)
   ,1 ,"A2" ,""    ,bool(null) ,""              ,datetime(2022-08-03 02:00)
   ,1 ,"A2" ,"def" ,bool(null) ,""              ,datetime(2022-08-03 03:00)
   ,1 ,"B"  ,""    ,bool(null) ,""              ,datetime(2022-08-04 00:00)
   ,1 ,"C"  ,""    ,true       ,""              ,datetime(2022-08-05 00:00)
   ,1 ,"D"  ,"xyz" ,bool(null) ,""              ,datetime(2022-08-06 00:00)
];
T
|   partition hint.strategy=native by PropertyId 
    (
            order by EventDate asc
        |   scan with 
            (
                step s1 : true =>   Owner           = coalesce(Owner        , s1.Owner)
                                   ,PropertyTitle   = coalesce(PropertyTitle, s1.PropertyTitle);
            )
        |   where NoisyNeighbour
    )
```

| PropertyId | Tenant | Owner | NoisyNeighbour | PropertyTitle | EventDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C | def | true | Title updated | 2022-08-05T00:00:00Z |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=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)

Comment: If you have millions of properties, please give it another try, using `partition hint.strategy = shuffle`